# what's A<int(int)> mean? What's this technology's name?

Tags: c++, templates

If i define a class like this

```
template <class T> class A { };
```

how can i use the argument when `T = int(int)`? 
This code I have never see before, where can i find some webpage about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(int)` is a function type. It's the type of a function that takes one `int` and returns an `int`.

Comment: I just don't konw how can i use the function type in class A. It can't be use like a type , just like a type parameter, and even use it like a value ,just like a non-type parameter, so why it exsits?

Comment: @user1400047: Ever used `std::function<>`, or `boost::function<>`?

Comment: @user1400047 Can you give an example of it being used like a non-type parameter?

Comment: @user1400047 You can do e.g. `template <class T> class A { T *m; };`.

Comment: @user1400047 A function signature is just a type like any other.